# Is a symmetric monoidal category ("tensor-category" in P. Deligne & J.S. Milne's vocabulary) neccessarily locally small?

Tags: symmetric-monoidal-categories

Let $(\mathcal{C},\otimes,\mathbf{1},\phi,\psi)$ (I will denote this by just $(\mathcal{C},\otimes)$) be a tensor-category (in P. Deligne & J.S. Milne's vocabulary, see https://www.jmilne.org/math/xnotes/tc2018.pdf), or we could call it a symmetric monoidal category.

Furthermore, assume that $(\mathcal{C},\otimes)$ is **closed**, by which we mean that for every object $B$ in $(\mathcal{C},\otimes)$ we have that $- \otimes B \dashv \underline{\text{Hom}}(B,-)$, i.e. that $\underline{\text{Hom}}(B,-)$ is right-adjoint to the functor $- \otimes B$.

Is it the case that $(\mathcal{C},\otimes)$ is neccessarily locally small?

The reason for asking, is the proof of proposition $3.2$ here: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/internal+hom#ClosedMonoidalCategory

It seems like they use yoneda:s embedding in the proof, which assumes that $(\mathcal{C},\otimes)$ is locally small, but the proof only assumes closed symmetric monoidal.

Comment: The word "category" means that Homs are sets (or, as some people say, it is "locally small").

Comment: @DenisT: are you saying that that is the convention in this area? It's certainly not always the case...

Comment: @DenisT what would be the point of saying that a category is locally small if that was the case (assuming you by "Homs" mean $\text{Hom}(-,-)$ and not $\underline{\text{Hom}}(-,-)$)? Sorry, I am quite ignorant.

Comment: @SamHopkins I'm pretty sure that *some people* say that manifolds are not assumed to be Hausdorff, or that some other people say that metric can assume value $+\infty$. But if you want to stick to the colloquial usage of a mathematical term, and want to be sure that what people know about categories apply to things which you want to call "categories" (in which case previous assumption should be satisfied), you should assume that morphisms are sets.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1250736/749534